# How to filter a ListBox with 100,000 items

Tags: windows-phone-8, optimization

I have a `ListBox` which have about 100,000 items. I want to filter the items based on what the user types in a `TextBox`.

I want to search in real time, so I handle `TextBox_OnTextChanged` event.

My first solution was to set `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` whenever the text changed. This is really slow.

I'm using `CollectionViewSource`, `ObservableCollection`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` but this does not make it faster.

Thanks All

Comment: Could you post the code you are running? You can edit the question to add your code. Someone can probably help you if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting limitation on text before calling on textbox change event? Like call the textbox on change event only when there are minimum 3 letters in the textbox.

For eg:

```
if(myTextBox.getText().length > 3) 
 // call text box on change event
```